# How to show locations name both in English and local language in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I want to show locations name both in English and local language like Maps app show in android.
Here is my code

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
   OnMapReadyCallback {

private final static String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private GoogleMap mMap;
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
     mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng dhaka = new LatLng(23.8103, 90.4125);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(dhaka));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(dhaka,10f));

}
}
```

But when i run this code all locations name in map is in English. But i want to the output like this

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeJpG.png) where the location name is both in English and Bengali.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the necessary info from the following links

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRegionCodes

http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry